# Preventing animated model from passing thru walls

Tags: unity

I have a character model that has a sword swing animation where with every swing the character takes 1 step forward. This model has a capsule collider and a kinematic rigidbody and use a CapsuleCast to detect collisions and prevent the player from passing thru whenever there's a collision (collider mainly used for me to get some bounds).

This collision detection works well when running, jumping, etc., but currently I am having problems with the sword swing I mentioned above. The animation is passing thru walls. Initially, it seems because the CapsuleCast origin goes inside the wall so it doesn't trigger a collision so I adjusted the CapsuleCast a little farther to the back but it still didn't work 100% of the time. Sometimes it passes thru depending on the distance I start the swing (or multiple swings).

Next, I tried to create a backup RayCast (also tried a backup CapsuleCast). It improved a bit but not 100% still.

I guess my question really here is more of can you give me idea an what I can try out to solve this.

Btw, the Animator has root motion turned off. Code is the one moving the model every sword swing.

**EDIT:**

Added relevant code

** Main Move method:

```
private void Move()
{
    _velocity.x = Input.HorizontalMove * _player.MoveSpeed;
    _velocity.z = Input.DepthMove * _player.DepthMoveSpeed;

    if (_velocity.y < 0)
        _velocity.y += _player.Gravity * _player.FallMultiplier * Time.deltaTime;
    else
        _velocity.y += _player.Gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    HandleAttack();

    CheckHorizontalCollisions();

    transform.Translate(_velocity * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    Physics.SyncTransforms();        
}
```

CheckHorizontalCollisions:

```
private void CheckHorizontalCollisions(bool checkForDepth = false)
{
    Vector3 direction;
    if (checkForDepth)
        direction = Vector3.forward * Mathf.Sign(_velocity.z);
    else
        direction = Vector3.right * Mathf.Sign(_velocity.x);

    float halfWidth = _collider.bounds.size.x / 2;

    // Top and bottom of capsule        
    Vector3 point1 = new Vector3(transform.position.x, _collider.bounds.max.y - halfWidth, transform.position.z);
    Vector3 point2 = new Vector3(transform.position.x, _collider.bounds.min.y + halfWidth, transform.position.z);        

    // Pick a value that is smaller than the player's collider width
    var capsuleSphereRadius = .1f;
    if (Physics.CapsuleCast(point1, point2, capsuleSphereRadius, direction, out RaycastHit hit, halfWidth - capsuleSphereRadius, ObstacleLayer))
    {
        var colliders = new Collider[3];
        int numOfHit = Physics.OverlapCapsuleNonAlloc(point1, point2, halfWidth, colliders, ObstacleLayer);

        for (var i = 0; i < numOfHit; ++i)
        {
            if (colliders[i].transform == hit.transform)
            {
                if (checkForDepth)
                    _velocity.z = 0;
                else
                    _velocity.x = 0;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HandleAttack:

```
private void HandleAttack()
{
    var directionChange = Vector3.zero;
    if (Input.AttackPressed)
    {
        State.IsAttacking = true;

        // Attack is a special case; play immediately so it feels responsive
        if (State.IsGrounded)
        {
            directionChange = _animator.DoAttack();
        }
    }

    if (State.IsAttacking && State.IsGrounded)
    {
        _velocity.x = directionChange.x * _player.MoveSpeed;
        _velocity.z = directionChange.z * _player.DepthMoveSpeed;
    }        
}
```

The _animator.DoAttack call just calls _animator.Play("Attack") and returns a Vector3 that is then used to move the model forward.

This is the original code, I removed the backup CapsuleCast/RayCast in CheckHorizontalCollisions as it seems its not working. Also, removed the part regarding vertical collisions and jumping to make code clearer and shorter for posting.

[image]

In this image, it won't go thru the wall (even though during animation the body does goe thru the wall), but if I stepped back a bit and do multiple swings, sometimes, the yellow line ends up inside the wall and then the CapsuleCast will fail.

**EDIT 2:**

Actually, even if the CapsuleCast's origin is in the middle of the collider, i'm confused why the CapsuleCast hits nothing. I tried adding ComputePenetration inside the CapsuleCast so the collider gets pushed back, but the problem is the CapsuleCast isn't returning a hit.

I positioned the character same as above and put the CapsuleCast origin back to collider center.x. Then I did a frame-by-frame and it seems the CapsuleCast initially isn't inside the wall; only near the full duration of the animation does the CapsuleCast end up inside the wall. So why did it not trigger a hit when it leaned thru the wall so ComputePenetration gets called?

Added this image as requested:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us your spherecast and movement code?

Comment: @DMGregory: Added what I think are the relevant code.

Comment: Also added a picture, the yellow line is where the CapsuleCast is now (it used to be in the center.x of the collider but the center.x of collider goes thru the wall so I moved it back. It helped a bit but still goes thru with a high rate of it happening.

Comment: Also, my apologies. I've edited the original question and replaced all instances of sphere to capsule. I typed wrongly the first time and only noticed when I re-read everything.

Comment: Show us the line where you assign a value to variable `ObstacleLayer`.

Comment: Its assigned via the inspector. WIll add a screenshot.

Comment: I can't realize if your walls are textured planes or if you are using an orthogonal projection (or both). Does your walls have a BoxCollider component added? 2D is more like an artistic decision today, but it is better if colliders have volume, or they may never be hit by a raycast, for example. An orthogonal projection won't give away that to the player anyway. Check your colliders, they must not have two sizes set to zero (or none while you are debugging this). Add them to walls if not done yet.

Comment: Assuming all colliders are set correctly (it's always good to double check), I'm very sure we are hitting this same issue: https://forum.unity.com/threads/raycasting-to-intersect-with-an-animated-characters-surface.30708/

Because it works when running/walking It looks like the same issue. In the link there are some suggestions that may work for you including some code. Note: pooverfish's solution (I didn't test it myself) is functional but isn't what I would do.